# Web server has no permission to access files on network drive

Tags: permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, ddev

I want to use DDEV as a local development environment. The setup was successful and the website (a WordPress) is running.

Currenty our team is using XAMPP and to avoid downloading large files on every local machine we create symbolic links (e.g. the "uploads" folder in WordPress). The target is a network drive. So everyone in our team has access to the same files.

Now I want to do the same with DDEV. In WSL I mounted the network drive and created a symbolic link. Inside the console I have full access to the mounted directory, I can create, edit and remove files.

But when I access a file with the browser I get the following error message:

> 403 Forbidden. You don't have permission to access this resource.

The same error occurs when I try to upload a new file within WordPress.

Is there any way to give the webserver the permission to view and modify the files on a network drive?

The Webserver is an Apache/2.4.38.

Comment: Remember that the filesystem on the host (WSL2 in this case) is not the same as the one in the container. So you'll have to 1) Mount the external filesystem into the container, probably with a docker-compose.*.yaml and then 2) Inside the web container create a symlink that works to it. You can study this inside the web container `ddev ssh` and when the symlink works there, you're good. Happy to help you figure this out if you have an exact example. They key is that you have to mount it into the *container*.

Comment: You will need a docker-compose.mountuploads.yaml based on https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/custom-compose-files/#docker-compose42yaml-examples and add a `volumes` section to the web service, with an item that works, like `- /host/path/to/uploads:/mnt/uploads` and then you can so a symlink to /mnt/uploads as needed.  Beware that docker may not be able to mount network drives this way at all.

Comment: Another note: For this exact situation Drupal has a nice module called stage_file_proxy that eliminates the need to even bring down this type of files. If WP has something like that... https://www.drupal.org/project/stage_file_proxy

Comment: @rfay I created the docker-composer file. Now I can access the uploads folder within ddev ssh. But when I try creating files (e.g. with `touch`) it returns following error message:`touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': Permission denied`
In my test case I need different credentials to access the network drive. Could that be the reason? 
This is my docker-compose-file:
`volumes:
    - /var/www/html/web/app/uploads:/mnt/t/ddev-test/uploads`

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the Drupal module. Looks like there are a few also for WordPress but it seems they're not maintained anymore.

Comment: @rfay the owner of the uploads directory is "root". But all other files of my project are owned by me.

Comment: You may want to change the permissions on your uploads directory (at the source). You'll need to figure out the network details yourself. I'm afraid I can't offer much counsel.  What kind of filesystem is the source on? I see a number of discussions of this type of problem at https://www.google.com/search?q=docker+mount+network+share&oq=docker+mount+network+&aqs=chrome.0.0l2j69i57j0l2j0i22i30j0i22i30i395l2.3260j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Sorry for the late update, I was in home office until now and couldn't test it. Now I want to try again resolving the problem. But it seems I stuck on a very basic docker problem.
I created a file within the .ddev directory with the name "docker-compose.mountuploads.yaml" and looks like this:
services:
  web:
    volumes:
    - /var/www/html/web/app/uploads:/mnt/m/ddev-test/uploads

This is just a test and I thought I can access via `ddev ssh` the route `/var/www/html/web/app/uploads` but this folder doesn't exists.

Comment: The mount formula is "source:dest", so the host-side path goes on the left, and the docker-side path goes on the right. I'm pretty sure your host-side isn't /var/www/html

Comment: I switched both parts and now it works, also with the network drive! I'm not sure what solved exacatly the main problem, because in the meanwhile the privileges were updated on the network drive. So many thanks your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rfay mentioned I had to add the network drive as volume so it's accessible by the web container. Therefore I created a new docker-compose-file within the .ddev directory (see also in the docs: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/custom-compose-files/#docker-compose42yaml-examples).

Additionally the permissions on the network drive were incorrect.